# Activating a custom domain with a "naked" domain

Tags: community, custom-domain

A few days ago, I created three domains and custom URLs for some community sites. Two of them are now working perfectly, but they are subdomains of a domain.

The final domain, for some reason, I can't create in Setup because apparently the CNAME still isn't pointing correctly. The difference with this domain, is I want it to be a domain by itself, not a subdomain (eg. simply typing xxxxx.com should take you straight to the community homepage).

However I read online that CNAME is usually used for subdomains. Could this be why it's not working? And if so, what can I do to point the whole domain to the community?

Thanks!
James

Comment: This type of domain is known as a "naked" or (more technically correct) "apex" domain. It won't let you activate the custom domain in SF until [DNS is correctly set up for apex domain](https://serverfault.com/questions/613829/why-cant-a-cname-record-be-used-at-the-apex-aka-root-of-a-domain). https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.domain_mgmt_naked_domains.htm&type=5 answers your questions.

Comment: @identigral You should add this as an answer.